# Google Bar chart labeling Dynamic data.How to add labels?

Tags: php, json, google-visualization, bar-chart

I am creating  a Google charts bar chart! The data comes from MySQL, using JSON and PHP.
All I would like is to put labels at the end of Bar charts. Because data are dynamic, i found it difficult.

```
<?php
   $sth = mysql_query("select * from table");
   $rows = array();
   //flag is not needed
   $flag = true;
   $table = array();
   $table['cols'] = array(
                    array('label' => 'Stats', 'type' => 'string'),
                    array('label' => 'Value', 'type' => 'number')
                    );
   $rows = array();
   while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) 
   {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['Stats']); 
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Value']); 
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
   }
    $table['rows'] = $rows;
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
?>  
<script type="text/javascript">
   google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
   function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);
      var options = {
            legend: {position: 'none'},
        bar: {groupWidth: "85%"},
        colors:['#4A9218'],
        hAxis: {
                    viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
                    viewWindow: {
                                 max: 400,
                                 min: 0,
                                 },
                     gridlines: {
                              count: 10,
                                }
                            }          
   };
   var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
   chart.draw(data, options);
 }
</script>
<!--this is the div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="chart_div" style="width:100%; height:200px"></div>
```

Outcome :
Bar chart with no labeling
Outcome I am looking for:
Bar chart with labeling at the end on the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` to your `json_encode` call, as MySQL outputs numbers as strings, and inputting numbers as strings can cause problems with some charts:

```
$jsonTable = json_encode($table, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

If you want to add the data values as annotations on the bars, the easiest way is to create a DataView that includes a calculated `'annotation'` role column that takes its data from the value column and stringifies it:

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation',
    sourceColumn: 1,
    calc: 'stringify'
}]);
```

Then use the view to draw your chart instead of the DataTable:

```
chart.draw(view, options);
```